# Почему не работает эта программа в Android?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.axelreader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Текст");

    }
}
```

По идее, это приложение должно выводить на экран слово Текст. Что может быть проще? Но выдается такая вот ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.axelreader, PID: 14469
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.axelreader/com.example.axelreader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7091)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.axelreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7091) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

За что и почему в Android так сложно и мудрено? Ну и конечно как избавиться от сей ошибки?

Comment: Покажи разметку.

Comment: Которую даже не установили в активность: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` (перед нахождением `TextView`)

Answer (score 4):

У вас переменная textView null, т.к. findViewById(R.id.textView1); не может найти в разметке активити такого виджета по такому ID. А найти не может, т.к. вы никакой разметки в активити не загрузили.

Чтобы загрузить разметку в активити вызовите

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`